# How to Determine if a week is odd or even

Tags: android

I want to determine week whom has today is even or odd!

I wrote this code but that not work.

```
public static int getWeekType(Date termStartDate, Date dateToday){
    Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();
    today.setTime(dateToday);

    Calendar thatDay = Calendar.getInstance();
    thatDay.setTime(termStartDate);

    long diff = today.getTimeInMillis() - thatDay.getTimeInMillis(); //result in millis
    long days = diff / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);

    int dayOfWeek = (today.getTime().getDay() + 1) % 7;
    int weekNum = (int) ((days + dayOfWeek) / 7);
    return (weekNum + 1) % 2; // 0(even) or 1(odd)
}
```

how i can do it?

**EDIT:**

sample of result:

```
06-10 04:53:16.690    I/week-type﹕ ---- week type: 1 - Thu Jun 18 04:52:21 GMT 2015
06-10 04:53:17.858    I/week-type﹕ ---- week type: 1 - Fri Jun 19 04:52:21 GMT 2015
06-10 04:53:18.674    I/week-type﹕ ---- week type: 0 - Sat Jun 20 04:52:21 GMT 2015
06-10 04:53:19.474    I/week-type﹕ ---- week type: 1 - Sun Jun 21 04:52:21 GMT 2015
06-10 04:53:20.622    I/week-type﹕ ---- week type: 1 - Mon Jun 22 04:52:21 GMT 2015
06-10 04:53:21.390    I/week-type﹕ ---- week type: 1 - Tue Jun 23 04:52:21 GMT 2015
06-10 04:53:22.890    I/week-type﹕ ---- week type: 0 - Wed Jun 24 04:52:21 GMT 2015
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what exactly doesn't work? Perhaps give an example input and describe what output you're getting and how it differs from what you'd expect?

Comment: seeing as this is purely a java question, maybe replace android tag wiht java. for clarification: if you want to know whether today is the day of an even or odd week (in the current year?), then why does your function have two dates as input? or you want to know if the two dates weeks (of the year) are an even or odd number apart? or whether the difference of the days in weeks is even or odd?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate the `weekNum` directly from the difference in milliseconds between the two dates:

This should work:

```
public static int getWeekType(Date termStartDate, Date dateToday){
    Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();
    today.setTime(dateToday);

    Calendar thatDay = Calendar.getInstance();
    thatDay.setTime(termStartDate);

    long diff = today.getTimeInMillis() - thatDay.getTimeInMillis(); //result in millis
    long weekNum = diff / (7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);

    return (weekNum + 1) % 2; // 0(even) or 1(odd)
}
```

If you want to count from the start of the week that contains termStartDate, then modify it to add the day of the week of `thatDate` not `today`:

```
public static int getWeekType(Date termStartDate, Date dateToday){
    Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();
    today.setTime(dateToday);

    Calendar thatDay = Calendar.getInstance();
    thatDay.setTime(termStartDate);

    long diff = today.getTimeInMillis() - thatDay.getTimeInMillis(); //result in millis
    long days = diff / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);

    int dayOfWeek = thatDay.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) - 1;
    int weekNum = (int) ((days + dayOfWeek) / 7);
    return (weekNum + 1) % 2; // 0(even) or 1(odd)
}
```

Note: getDay() is deprecated so I changed it to use `Calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)`.